# Can I assign the "New Window" hotkey in Mac OSX to a particular theme?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, shortcut, hotkeys

In the Mac OSX Terminal app, I want to press command-N and get a new window with the Homebrew theme.  I have edited my preferences so that on startup of the Terminal app I get a Hombrew-themed window, but I'd like to be able to create new windows (and tabs if that's not too much to ask for) with that same theme.

I've tried assigning a new hotkey in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Application Shortcuts.  I created a new hotkey for Terminal, and specified "Homebrew" as the command.  This did not work.  have I specified the name of the menu command incorrectly, or am I just going about this wrong?

I also dug around a bit in the Terminal.app folder (using the shell), looking for a config file where I could set this, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default profile by clicking the default button under the list of profiles in the second tab.

If others were looking how to create a window with a specific profile, you can change the current settings property or use UI scripting:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script ""
    set current settings of window 1 to settings set "Homebrew"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal"
    click menu item "Homebrew" of menu 1 of menu item "New Window" of menu "Shell" of menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
end tell
```